# Is there a study indicating a neurological reward for agreeing with group beliefs?

Tags: psychology, social

I know a study in 2011 showed activation on the ventromedial PFC (part of the reward system that lights up when we see something we want, like chocolate) when opinions of others were shown. I'm assuming it activated upon learning the opinions of the others because it anticipated a reward following agreement with the group.

I know Matz and Wood (2005) published a study showing cognitive dissonance following differing opinions from group members, motivating a change of beliefs to resolve it. Do you know of any studies showing a neurological reward following agreement with others? I'm probably searching using the wrong keywords, but I can't seem to find anything.

I'd assume there is at least research showing a neurological reward when social media posts get likes or supportive comments.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE!  Your question seems a bit muddled to me.  The title asks about neurological reward for agreeing with group beliefs (bandwagon effect or "groupthink"), but then the tail end of the body of the question asks about neurological reward when seeing social media likes and supportive comments.  Can you clarify exactly what you are after please?

Comment: Can you please also provide references for the 2011 study and the study by Matz and Wood (2005)? That way others can benefit from background reading to what you are talking about.

Comment: 1. I'm after the former. The latter would at least indicate reward when others agree with us.

Comment: I believe it's the only paper Matz and Wood published that year